# ASP.NET Web API 4 unexpected end of mime multipart stream

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

so i have an old angular 2-rc4 project that runs on asp.net web api 4, I'm trying to implement file uploading and I'm having an issue with posting a file from the front end.

i get the error `unexpected end of mime multipart stream`

this only happens in the client project, if i send a request from postman the file uploads successfully, any ideas what could cause this to happen?

What I've tried so far

I read that we may need to append a CRLF to the end of the stream so implement this, which still didn't fix the issue

```
                reqStream.Position = 0;
                MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
                reqStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
                
                tempStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempStream);
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Flush();
                tempStream.Position = 0;

                StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(tempStream);
                foreach (var header in Request.Content.Headers)
                {
                    streamContent.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
```

Here's the front end code that sends the request

```
        let body = JSON.stringify(jobFilesUpload);

        const fileHeaders = new Headers();
        fileHeaders.append('Accept', '*/*');
        fileHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        fileHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');

        this.authHttp.post(this.authService.apiUrl + "api/upload" + jobFilesUpload.OBPJobId, body, { headers: fileHeaders }).subscribe(do more stuff here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the way i was calling the endpoint to use XHR

```
var fd = new FormData();
for (var i in this.FilesList) {
    fd.append("fileToUpload", this.FilesList[i], this.FilesList[i].name);
    this.FilesList[i].Comments = this.FileComments;
}

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let url = this.authService.apiUrl + "api/SaveOBPJobFiles";

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.authService.userToken.JWT);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                        // Display success or failure to user
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

                        if (response.success == true) {
                                self.Item.OBPJobFiles = response.obpJobFiles;
                                self.Item.FileCount = response.obpJobFiles.length;
                                self.ClearOBPFiles();
                                console.log("File Success");
                                console.log(response.productionFiles);
                        } else {
                                self.toastrService.Error(response.message);
                        }

                        self.OBPFileProcessing = false;
                        setTimeout(() => {
                                self.systemService.StopLadda();
                        }, 1);
                } else {

                        self.OBPFileProcessing = false;
                        setTimeout(() => {
                                self.systemService.StopLadda();
                        }, 1);
                }
        }

        xhr.send(fd);
```

seemed to fix the original issue for anyone else struggling.